# Running DTS packages on SQL Server 2012

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, dts

I read that DTS packages aren't supported in SQL Server 2012. I know there's a Backward Compatibility package/option out there that we used for SQL Server 2008R2 to run DTS packages. Will that Backwards compatibility package not work for SQL Server 2012?

For 2008 R2
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500440(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: DTS was replaced with SSIS in the 2005 product. Since then we've had 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012, and 2014 will soon be in preview. Have you not had enough time to consider re-writing these packages?

Comment: Not sure why I was downvoted. It's a valid question. Our company supports version SQL Server 2000 on several of our clients. As much as we'd wish to get them off 2000, they are still on it. Right now, we are simply researching and gathering information (and confirmation) for all our options.

Comment: I didn't downvote - but 2000 fell off of even *extended* support from Microsoft in April this year. It's time for those customers to upgrade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the documentation [says](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500429.aspx), support for "migrating or running" DTS packages was completely discontinued in SQL Server 2012. Even if you convince your customers to move to SQL 2012, you'll have to upgrade the packages to 2008 first and then upgrade again to 2012, so the sooner they agree to upgrade to *some* newer version the better, although I appreciate that - rightly or wrongly - many customers will not see the point in paying to upgrade something that still works.

Answer (score 1):

If the customer is not ready to invest in the DTS to SSIS migration project, better to use SQL server 2008/r2 to run DTS 2000 packages.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500440(v=sql.105).aspx