# Run SQL Server 2008 R2 DTSX on SQL Server 2012/2014

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a DTSX file created with SQL Server 2008 R2 (package saved from Import/Export Tool on SQL Managemente Studio); Does it run on SQL Server 2012/2014?

Comment: Was it done through ssis visual studio or import/export tool from sql studio?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682724/how-to-run-2008r2-ssis-packages-on-sql-server-2014-standard-environment

Comment: @RhianA It was created with import/export tool from sql server management studio (option "Save SSIS Package")

Comment: I think [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986522/running-dts-packages-on-sql-server-2012) you'll have your answers about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...I've tested with SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition and it runs DTS file (with "Execute Package Utility") correctly.